# Error NetBeans 8.2: Libraries array contains a null reference: [null]

Tags: netbeans, null

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación con un EJB Stateless con NetBeans 8.2 y GlassFish 5. La he hecho antes sin problemas. Creo que es un problema de reutilizar NetBeans sin reinstalarlo de nuevo tras varios años. La aplicación son tres pequeños proyectos: Una librería de clases (que contendrá la interfaz remota del EJB), un proyecto Java EE con el módulo del EJB de sesión y un único método de prueba y la aplicación cliente Java EE para simplificar la llamada. Al crear el módulo EJB, le doy la librería de clases para que meta allí la interfaz remota correspondiente al EJB que luego se distribuye al cliente... pues ahí falla, parece un error interno de NetBeans, que no logra encontrar esa librería. No he encontrado casi nada al respecto por internet. ¿Alguien conoce este bug o error?